# Segfault only when using pkg-config --libs for glib.h

Tags: c, gcc, glib, cc

I have the following piece of code, compiled with `` gcc `pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0` test.c -o test `` the code works, but only when I use `` gcc `pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0` test.c -o test `` the code gets segfault when running.

```
#include <glib.h>     

typedef struct _mystruct{
    int a;
}my;                                                                         
                                                                                               
static void set_int(my *mert){                                                                 
  mert->a = 5;                                                                                   
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                           
int main() {                                                                                                                                                        
  my *myInt;                                                                                                                                                                             
  set_int(myInt);                                                                                                                                                                    
}
```

I tried with GDB, when the program is compiled with `--libs` the segfault comes from here

```
0x0000000000401132 in set_int (mert=0x0) at test.c:5
5       mert->a = 5;
```

But when it is compiled only with `--cflags` all is on its place

```
Breakpoint 1, set_int (mert=0x7ffff7ffdab0 <_rtld_local+2736>) at test.c:5
5       mert->a = 5;
```

I have also tried with `` gcc `pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0` test.c -o test `pkg-config --libs glib-2.0` `` but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: You never initialize `myInt` so the expression `mert->a = 5` in `set_int` will lead to undefined behaviour -- pure and simple.  Nothing to do with `pkg-config` I'm afraid.

Comment: @G.M There is a log of GDB without using --libs and that line of code is working, I only get segfault when using --libs and there is also the log of that in the post

Comment: I think the compiler should also give you a warning that you are trying to access data through an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: @nevermindmyname the advice that GM gave you is correct. No matter how you build, you can't depend on that uninitialized pointer to work right -- give it a value with malloc() or something similar.

Comment: *There is a log of GDB without using --libs and that line of code is working*  No, it  was **never** "working".  Undefined behavior from dereferencing an uninitialized pointer never "works".  It just may not blow up and fail in an observable manner.

Answer (score 3):

`myInt` is an uninitialized pointer and it happens to be NULL in the case where your program is segfault'ing.  You pointer needs to reference a struct as `set_int()` dereferences said pointer:

```
int main() {             
  my myInt;                            
  set_int(&myInt);
}
```

Or you could could zero initialize your struct and take it's address if you want `myInt` to be a pointer:

```
int main() {
  my *myInt = &(my) { 0 };
  set_int(myInt);
}
```